# How to include model to another in django

Tags: python, django

I have this database in mongodb

```
picture:"http://placehold.it/150x150"
name:"Gushkool"
email:"leilaware@gushkool.com"
city:"Rabat"
location:Object
         type:"Point"
         coordinates:Array
                     0:-6.81134
                     1:33.95564
```

I want create models like this database and this is my shot:

```
class location(Document):
   type = fields.StringField()
   coordinates = fields.StringField()

class products(Document):
   picture = fields.StringField()
   name = fields.StringField()
   email = fields.StringField()
   city = fields.StringField()
   location = ReferenceField(location)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> class mongoengine.fields.EmbeddedDocumentField(document_type, **kwargs)

An embedded document field - with a declared document_type. Only valid values are subclasses of EmbeddedDocument.

change your model to:

```
class location(EmbeddedDocument):
  type = fields.StringField()
  coordinates = fields.ListField()

class products(Document):
  picture = fields.StringField()
  name = fields.StringField()
  email = fields.StringField()
  city = fields.StringField()
  location = fields.EmbeddedDocumentField('location')
```

and in your view

```
lct = location(type="test")
#lct.save() don't use save
prt = products(picture="aaa",name="aaa",email="aaa",city="aaa")
prt.location= lct
prt.save()
```